# This error occurs irregularly "Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection~"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using .Net Framework 4.5 and I get the following error:

"Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection ~" Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported. "

What I'm curious about is that this error doesn't always occur, about 50 times? It means that an error occurs about once a day.
I don't know what to do because it only occurs in the production environment and has never occurred in the local test.
If you know the exact cause, please let me know.

Best regard.

The simplified source is below.

```
public PartialViewResult update(string id)
{
    List<Item> list;
    try
    {
        var business = new Business();
        using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            business.Update(id);
            ts.Complete();
        }

        if (result)
        {
            list = business.GetList();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return PartialView("Error");
        }

        return PartialView("PartialContent", list);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return PartialView("Error");
    }
}

public class Business
{
    public List<Item> GetList()
    {
        var dao = new Repository();
        var list = dao.GetList().ToList();
        return list;
    }
    
    public void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            var dao = new Repository();
            var item = dao.Get(id);
            item.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            dao.Update(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}


public class Repository
{
    private SampleContext context;

    private Repository()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new SampleContext();
        }
    }
    
    public IQueryable<Item> GetList()
    {
        // SQL
    }
    public IQueryable<Item> Get(string id)
    {
        // SQL
    }
    public void Update(Item item)
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Add.
I tried to modify Repository by comment of Le Vu.

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    private SampleContext context;

    private Repository()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new SampleContext();
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Item> GetList()
    {
        // SQL
    }
    public IQueryable<Item> Get(string id)
    {
        // SQL
    }
    public void Update(Item item)
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The reason for committing in the middle is that even if an error occurs in reacquiring the data after the update, we want to continue the update process as it is.

Comment: Have you try calling Dispose DbContext in Repository. I think DbContext hold unmanaged resources related to DB connection.

Comment: At what stage should DbContext be disposed?
If you do it in each process, it will be "The operation cannot be completed. DbContext has been destroyed."
* Because it is translated into English, it may differ from the actual English message.

Comment: Your `Repository` class should implement `IDisposable` interface. The interface has `Dispose()` method. This method will be called when GC collect the unused objects.  You should call DbContext disposing in `Dispose()` of Repository. Also, take care about your `Business` instance lifetime

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
You need to make the Repository Disposible.
I put the modified source in the text.
Is it something like this?

Without this, it may remain without being discarded, and does it mean that an error occurs when the destruction happens to be delayed?

Comment: Yes, you know, Garbage Collector is a feature of CLR. It means it only takes care resource come from CLR environment. These resources are called managed resources. Otherwise, about unmanaged resources such as DB connections in this case, the GC doesn't know about its existence. Anyway, You're missing checking `null` on  `context`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the commentary.
When it comes to changing the original Repository, I have to check if there is any other effect, but I would like to try this.
If you could answer instead of commenting, I would like your answer to be the best answer. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is the unmanaged resources related to `SampleContext`(DbContext) have not been released especially database connections here.

The resolution is the instance of `SampleContext` need explicitly dispose. It means, we need to implement `IDisposable` interface in `Repository` class. And in `Dispose`, we will dispose the instance of `SampleContext` (if exist).

The lifetime of `Business` object on `update` Action is also a matter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering!
It is very easy to understand because it even draws a figure. appreciate.

As for Business, we don't have unmanaged resources, so I don't think it's okay to do an explicit GC. Is that correct?

Comment: As you can see, Business has dependencies on Repository, SampleContext. In .NET Framework, Garbage collection is not frequently occurring. In case, you don't dispose Repository object in Business object when `update` action is done, the DB connection will wait until GC clean up. You have knowledge the scope of DB calls, so you can control when should release the DB. You can add a `finally` block in `update` action to release resources,

Comment: sorry. I understand.
When I modified the source earlier, I only implemented IDisposable in the repository, and did not actually enclose the instance in "using".

Comment: Yes, that is what I want you to notice. You can keep the repository alive along with the Business object or only in the function scope. Usually, we use IoC Container to control DbContext from outside to inside. It makes the performance better. The best practice is we only dispose the object which is created in the class. For object which passed into the class, we don't touch its lifetime.

Comment: Your comments made me understand well.
Thank you for staying with me for a long time.
I was very helpful and the answer was convincing.
Thank you very much.